# SWIFT - HTML scrolling events in a WKWebView that's inside a ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, wkwebview

I have a web page for testing purposes (https://storage.googleapis.com/htmltestingbucket/nested_scroll_helper.html) that just prints a counter of the scroll event the html has caught in a fixed header

When the WKWebView is the only scroll-able element in the fragment everything is fine and the WebView sends the scroll events to the page

If I want to add native elements above and below the WebView then things get much more complex.

```
UIScrollView  
    UILabel
    WKWebView
    UILabel
```

I know it's not good to have a WebView inside a ScrollView but I have to provide a single scrolling experience with hybrid content and proper scrolling events in the html document. I found plenty of questions on the matter but I was not able to create a full end-to-end solution.

Answer (score 5):

**Update:**
Okay took me a while to understand what you're trying to do.

I know you would like to keep the outer scrollView, but I'm pretty sure it's not possible to achieve what you want to do (only way could be if you set the `outerScrollView.delegate = webView` - but didn't work for me when I tried)

I think the best solution would be:

1. remove your outer scrollView
2. set the contentInsets for your webView to whatever height on top and bottom you need. E.g. for 100pt : `webView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(100,0,100,0);`
3. Add your UIElements as subView to your UIWebView instead of the UIScrollView (basically into the free space you created with your contentInsets)

---

**Previously (Other way around):**

1. set up a height constraint of your UIWebView
2. store the height constraint as IBOutlet in your UIViewController
3. set `webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;` in your `viewDidLoad` or the storyboard
4. as soon as the webView is loaded, extract its content height `webView.scrollView.contentSize.height`
5. update the UIWebView height constraint with the value of it`s content height via`self.webViewContentHeightConstraint.constant = `webView.scrollView.contentSize.height`
6. call [self.scrollView layoutIfNeeded]; to make sure your view gets rendered again

Don`t forget to do steps 4 & 5 whenever the webView did finish loading content

[image]

Comment: But how the webview will be aware of the scrolls?

Comment: It won't because you wont scroll in the webview anymore. You will only have one scrollable view, that "moves" the webview. Thereby you have a perfect single scroll experience

Comment: I get you, but that is the oposite of what we are looking for. I need the webview to be aware of the scroll while scrolling on it

Comment: so you want the uiwebview to be aware that you are scrolling in the parent scrollView? If yes, I can adjust my answer. Otherwise, pls give me some more context

Comment: Yes. Please adjust your answer

Comment: The content of the web view is a black box for me. I can't add anything inside

Comment: but you can still adjust the contentInset on the webView instance, right? No need to change the html content

Comment: can you mark this as correct answer if it solved your problem please?

Answer (score 0):

You basically have a scrollview inside a scrollview. How do you suppose that would work? I would add the labels to the HTML in the WebView. Don't see any reason why they need to be native.

Alternatively, you could try to add the labels to the UIWebView's UIScrollView. That's it's first subview. Not sure if you need to adjust the scrollview insets. Injecting html probably would work more reliably.